# created collection trying to delete the duplicated records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created the collection test_emp

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e84200bdf949c00404ed5ff"),
    "area" : "573",
    "bc" : "NZ",
    "bd" : "52001450",
    "bg" : "52001450",
    "borg" : "f52001450",
    "bsg" : "54878",
    "bsgname" : "INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
    "o" : "S",
    "friendlyCountryName" : "NZ",
    "ctel" : "+1",
    "mail" : "tl2625@nz.at.com",
    "exch" : "204",
    "ext" : "5408",
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber" : null,
    "givenName" : "POMAS",
    "employeeNumber" : "45629"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e84200bdf949c00404ed600"),
    "area" : "573",
    "bc" : "NZ",
    "bd" : "52001450",
    "bg" : "52001450",
    "borg" : "f52001450",
    "bsg" : "54878",
    "bsgname" : "INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
    "o" : "S",
    "friendlyCountryName" : "NZ",
    "ctel" : "+1",
    "mail" : "tl2625@nz.at.com",
    "exch" : "204",
    "ext" : "5408",
    "facsimileTelephoneNumber" : null,
    "givenName" : "POMAS",
    "employeeNumber" : "45629"
}
```

I want to delete the duplicate records  , first checking with below queries for aggregate function:

```
db.test_emp.aggregate({ $group: { _id: { "employeeNumber": "$employeeNumber", "givenName" : "$givenName" }}})



Error:
TypeError: pipeline[(pipeline.length - 1)] is undefined 
Details:
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:236:1
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

Also tried with delete  duplicate command:

```
db.test_emp.ensureIndex( { employeeNumber:1 }, { unique:true, dropDups:true } )

errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: phone.test_emp index: employeeNumber_1 dup key: { : \"0249527\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
```

please suggest wht queries to be used to delete these duplicate records from collection.

Comment: Thanks experts, am not able to  acheive it now....could you please update me all the steps which need to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of problems.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "employeeNumber": "$employeeNumber",
        "givenName": "$givenName"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

1. `aggregate query` should be enclosed by `[]`
2. You cannot create index on existing collection as you have duplicate data already.

So what you can do now:

1. Create a collection
2. Create unique indices - the second command which you tried
3. Create dump from your existing collection `mongodump`
4. Load into new collection.
5. Drop your old collection.
6. Rename the new collection to your old collection name

Comment: thanks experts, i tried with db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "employeeNumber": "$employeeNumber",
        "givenName": "$givenName"
      }
    }
  }
]) and it's giving an outptu now how can i  remove duplicate records from collection now.

Comment: With that its not easy to do so. You can follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: have tried the steps: getting error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: webphone.testcollection index: employeeNumber_1 dup key: { : "0249527" }

Comment: Can you add the commands which you tried one by one? So that I can look into it.

Comment: db.createCollection("testcollection")


db.testcollection.ensureIndex( { employeeNumber:1 }, { unique:true, dropDups:true } )

Comment: db.testcollection.insert( {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e84200bdf949c00404ed600"),
    "area" : "573",    .......... while doping insert it throwing error

Comment: No, You need to use `mongodump` to load into newer collection and wherever duplicate keys are there, it will just complain and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is less complex if you don't want to preserve `_id` key of the documents.

```
db.test_emp.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$_id"}
    },
    {
        "$out": "test_emp2"
    }
])
```

Then you can delete the original collection and replace the newly created temp collection to the original collection.

```
db.test_emp.drop()
db.test_emp2.renameCollection("test_emp")
```

**WARNING:** You have to restore the original collection indexes manually if you do this. Also, the `_id` key won't be preserved.

> Take a backup before proceeding with this mentodoligy.

Note: [@Gibbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62812423/8213277) answer to this is much preferred if you want to preserve `_id` and you are familiar with `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands.